# How to delay IIS reboot server?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I would like to know if it's possible to delay the IIS reboot after installing a solution using `Add-SPSolution`?

We would like to reboot server during the night.

Thanks

Comment: Schedule the install to run at night if it automatically reboots.

Comment: `Add-SPSolution` should only recycle the App Pool, if it's restarting IIS you've got a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PowerShell script with combination of Add-SPSolution / Install-SPSolution commands and schedule execution of the PS script over night.

Comment: we can use 'time' parameter with Install-SPSolution also !